# the lifecycle of managedObjectContext (or variable) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use CoreData with swift and MagicalRecord.
I have a question about the lifecycle of variable.

```
func reloadTable() {
        ...

        let numberObject = try! NSManagedObjectContext.MR_context().existingObjectWithID(numberObjectId)
        assert(numberObject.managedObjectContext != nil)
        ...
}
```

sometimes, It will active the assert because managedObjectContext is nil. (I know managedObjectContext of nsmangedObject is weak...)

but...
if I change the code into .....

```
func reloadTable() {
        ...

        let localContext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_context()
        let numberObject = try! localContext.existingObjectWithID(numberObjectId)
        assert(numberObject.managedObjectContext != nil)
        ...
}
```

It seems never active the assert...

in objc, the variable will be existed during { .... }
but in swift, is it might released anytime if I didn't determined any variable for a return value of a constructer ?

Thanks

Comment: the issue is caused because objectWithID: always returns an object, even though the object isn't registered in the receiver managed object context. Seems in some circumstances objectRegisteredForID: is more informative. In any case, the conclusion is that the life-cycle methods do fire, but to take care with objectWithID: since it can result in an inconsistent object.

Comment: @MuhammadNoman The code above doesn't seem to use `objectWithID`.